# WinForms C# Событие закрывания формы ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, winforms

Если открывать новую форму в главной форме через Show(), то при его закрывании сработает событие Closed(). А вот когда открываю новую форму методом ShowDialog(), то событие Closed() не срабатывает. Есть ли какое нибудь событие при закрывании формы открытой с помощью метода ShowDialog()?

Comment: Если форма открыта через ShowDiaolog(), то при ее закрывании  не срабатывают события FormClosed() и FormClosing()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015, C# Windows Forms application project:

```
namespace test1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new Form2().ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}

namespace test1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: OK]

Работает. Вопрос, что вы сделали в вашем проекте, что оно не работает. Попробуйте сделать тест в новом проекте.

Comment: Спасибо! Просто у меня была ошибка. Код: 
form4 = new Form4();   form4.FormClosing += form4closed;
  form4.ShowDialog();
Т.е. я сначала открываю форму, а потом добавляю обработчик события. Еще раз спасибо.